# Как создать массив указателей на функции в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Как создать массив указателей на функции в C/C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо объявить новый тип - указатель на функцию. Это делается простым объявлением указателя на функцию. Далее необходимо объявить массив типа указателя на функцию. Например:

```
typedef void (*pfn_MyFuncType)(char * str, int len);
pfn_MyFuncType * myFuncTypeArray;
// или
pfn_MyFuncType myFuncTypeArray[10];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
void (*pfn_MyFuncType[10])(char * str, int len);
```

или

```
void (**pfn_MyFuncType)(char * str, int len);
```

Answer (score 0):

В стиле *C++11*:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


void foo(int i) 
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}


int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> vfunc;
    vfunc.push_back(foo);
    vfunc[0](1);
    return 0;
}
```